# Dismiss view based on background click

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView

```
var transparentBackground = UIView()
```

When a button is clicked, the view is given some properties

```
 @IBAction func UserViewImage(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {

        self.transparentBackground = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.transparentBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.4)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self.transparentBackground)
        self.opaqueView = self.setupOpaqueView()
        self.transparentBackground.addSubview(opaqueView)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: self.transparentBackground)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: transparentBackground)

    }
```

and when another button is clicked, the view is completely dismissed, with a function called removeAnimate.

```
func handleOKButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    removeAnimate()

}
```

However, I will like for when the background is clicked (the view) for the view to be completely dismissed, just like it is when the button is clicked, so I did this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(removeAnimate))
            self.transparentBackground.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

But its not working and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.Not that transparentBackground view has a subview in it.

```
 self.transparentBackground.addSubview(opaqueView)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented this:

```
viewDidLoad() {

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(close))

            gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

            gestureRecognizer.delegate = self

            view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func close() {

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: it's not working for me. The code that I listed in my question works on another view controller. I am not sure why it is not working in this one